# c++ iterating over several maps

Tags: c++

Hi have many instances of the same class that can be separated into two groups. I need to loop through either one of the two group or all of them. So I have two maps consisting of ids and shared_pointers to the instances.

```
map<long, shared_ptr<MyClass>>
```

Each map contains one of the two groups. Is there any significant performance benefit in having a third map with all items when I need to loop over all of them or is it that absolutely marginal. 
Is it generally considered ok practice to have shared pointers to instances in several containers or are there any reasons to limit that as much as possible?

EDIT: The maps will all be created at startup and wont need to be modified anymore.

Comment: There are many things we don't know, leaving all of them aside and focusing on your main question I would say: The overhead of maintaining a third map will most likely outweigh the benefit of having just one iteration instead of two. But, as always when talking about performance issues: Don't prematurely optimize. Don't pessimize. Measure!

Comment: I would like to second what Rene suggested. And ask, any reason why you do not use two loops (handling the first map and then the other)?